# ffmpeg - How to set MIME-type?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, mime-types

I'm trying to set the proper MIME-type for an AAC file, but this command does not work:

```
ffmpeg -i rain.mp3 -metadata mime-type="audio/aac" rainmp3toaac.aac
```

but, actualy `audio/x-hx-aac-adts` is set.

So, how I can force another MIME-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution after few day of researching. It's very simple:

```
ffmpeg -i rain.mp3 -f mp4 rainmp3toaac.aac
```

and now mime-type is `audio/mp4` and that is fine for me.